# DT-06 program using arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I'm working to program DT-06 wireless wifi module.

And right now when i'm trying to program i get the following error message : 
espcomm_send_command: can't receive slip payload data

Module RX - Arduino RX

TX - TX

VCC - 5v

GND - GND

Right now i can upload black program to arduino and send serial AT commands to my module and alson getting response.

How can i program ?

Thx

Appendix:

- Module:  https://www.banggood.com/Geekcreit-DT-06-Wireless-WiFi-Serial-Port-Transparent-Transmission-Module-TTL-To-WiFi-p-1141047.html

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry I think I misunderstood the question -- Do you want to Programm the DS-06 module or do you want to program an Arduino to talk to the DS-06 module? If it is the latter, what current code are you using?

Comment: i want to programm the DT-06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just program it like you would program a normal ESP8266.

The documentation is here:

- https://github.com/SmartArduino/SZDOITWiKi/wiki/ESP8266---TTLtoWiFi

The datasheet provides the schematic of the module

[image]

[image]

So SW2 is the reset button and "SW1" is the "FLASH" button. To enter the bootloader mode in which the ESP8266 can be programmed, you first have to hold down the "FLASH" button then press "RESET" once.

For programming you would ideally get a 5V USB-UART adapter make the connections

- VCC to 5V (it has a regulator to generate the actually needed 3.3V)
- GND to GND
- EN to 5V (e.g. via a pullup)
- TXD to RX of UART adapter
- RXD to TX of UART adapter

After the ESP is in the bootloader mode as described above, you can just program it normally through the Arduino IDE. Follow the instructions at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino to install the ESP8266-Arduino core in the board manager.

Refer to the similiar procedure:

- https://www.hackster.io/harshmangukiya/program-esp8266-esp-12e-with-arduino-using-ftdi-cable-2310c9

Comment: Thank you very much sir!  i'm new to this things. Thank you very much !

Comment: Right now i can flash the module like you show me. The code is uploaded but nothing in the serial monitor. #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
 
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
WiFi.softAP("Hello_IoT","12345678");
server.begin();
Serial.begin(115200);
IPAddress HTTPS_ServerIP= WiFi.softAPIP(); 
Serial.print("Server IP is: ");
Serial.println(HTTPS_ServerIP);
}

Comment: @user863873 Did you press the reset button (SW2) after flashing?

Comment: Yes. I get in serial the reset 2 and the rest of the info

Comment: More info : i haven 2 module. One i did flash it and the other one not. When i wire the second one (the one that i dont flash it) it responds in serial using arduinonto AT commandas. The second with the same wiring and code using same arduino does not. Maybe it helps

Comment: What is the output after reset on 38400 baud (bootloader messages?) Can you try to blink GPIO4? `pinMode(4, OUTPUT);` et cetera. @user863873

Comment: I don't know if i understand correctly. But i flash the following code : void setup() {
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
delay(1000);
} with no  blink led from my module. I did hit "reset"

Comment: What does the bootloader report? What USB/UART adapter are you using?

Comment: I'm using arduino to flash my module

Comment: i'm getting 100% when i flash my module

Comment: After i flash my module and "reset" i get : ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0xef
csum 0xef
csum err
ets_main.c

Comment: There is a checksum error because you probably selected the wrong module size. Try selecting a different board variant in the Arduino IDE with different flash sizes until one works. Could also be the flash mode (DIO/QIO) or you must mass-erase the flash once. See the https://www.letscontrolit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3071

Comment: That was the fix. After i set to ESP8285 all was good. Also i notice that i must have blank code in my arduino to be able to flash my module. Thank you sir !